# code working fine on zepplin but not working with spark-submit after compiling it with sbt

Tags: sbt, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin, arima, spark-submit

I am working with time series for stock market forcast . My spark scala script work fine on zeppelin but after compiling my script with sbt am not getting the results desired but jus null values. I have also an isssue concerning an unresolved dependency for com.cloudera.sparkts .

code line causing pb : [result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgjYP.png)

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(tsRdd.mapSeries { vector => {
val newVec = new org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector(vector.toArray.map(x => if (x.equals(Double.NaN)) 0 else x))
val arimaModel = ARIMA.fitModel(1, 0, 0, newVec)
val forecasted = arimaModel.forecast(newVec, DAYS)
new org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector(forecasted.toArray.slice(forecasted.size - (DAYS + 1), forecasted.size - 1))
}}.toJavaRDD).toDF("lab", "features").withColumn("featuresArr", vecToArray($"features"))

 df.select((col("lab") +: Array("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5").zipWithIndex.map { case (alias, idx) => col("featuresArr").getItem(idx).as(alias) }): _*).show
```

The output :

I got only null values

Answer (score 0):

Some of the dependencies issues are solved by reloading plugins and updating dependencies. Especially when the dependency issue is due to Ivy cache.

Do the following:

```
sbt reload plugins
sbt update
sbt reload
```

If you have issue check that the spark/scala version you define on your build is correct.

For the null values, I would start looking into the intermediaries step of the data pipeline and try to understand what is maybe wrong.

Comment: i still face same issue, i checked my built.sbt file

Comment: Can you share it? It would be great to see the spark/scala version and the dependency defined on the build.